# that's fine, that's OK or tomorrow is fine

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

If someone asks you if sending you the document you requested by (date) is Okay. Which answer is more idiomatic?

(date) is fine. (Is this OK in this context or only to confirm a meeting date?)
That's fine.
That's Okay (not sure about this one)

Thanks.

Comment: Monday is fine means you are happy with it. Monday is okay means you accept the date, but does not say you are happy. As a guest, don't say the food is okay if you want to be invited back.

Comment: None of these are idioms. *That's fine* or *That's ok* are both common responses; you do not need to repeat the date that the other person has suggested.